# Not able to creating new folder

Tags: android, directory, gallery

I am creating a gallery application.I have done displaying of the images in our phone  in my application(in corresponding folders). I have done this by taking the files which are of mime `type="image"`. Now I want to add the functionality "add new folder". I have added a plus button. So that new folder should be created. its working,new folder is creating. The problem is when run the application the created new folder is not displaying. The reason for this is there is no file inside the new folder. So mime type can not be checked. How can I achieve this functionality? Can anyone help me?

This is how I am creating folder:

```
    public File createFolder(String fname){
    String myfolder=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"Download"+"/"+fname;
    File f=new File(myfolder);
    if(!f.exists())
        if(!f.mkdirs()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myfolder+" can't be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("myfolder","cant create");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myfolder+" can be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("myfolder","created");
            return f;
        }

    else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myfolder+" already exits.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("myfolder","exist");
        return null;
    }

    return f;
}
```

Comment: What i understand from your question is : you want to display a folder which is created by your application even if it is empty right?

Comment: @Prashant absolutily as in our gallery application

Comment: In that case you can store the folder's path you created inside your application in db. and later it can be added to your list when application queries the folder which have image.